# ¿Como puedo crear un botón y que me permita reutilizarlo y así navegar en pantallas diferentes - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, vscode, programación-móvil, librería, sdk

Hola estoy tratando de hacer mi código reutilizable y estoy haciendo un botón, pero no sé como darle una ruta diferente si es el mismo botón. Me explico, quiero hacer un botón con parámetros, al hacer el llamado quiero implementar una ruta diferentes en varias botones. Mi código esta así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el botón y si se finjan tiene una ruta en el onpressed

```
class Buttons extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color textColor;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final String text;
  final double sizeW;
  final double sizeH;
  const Buttons(
      {super.key,
      required this.textColor,
      required this.backgroundColor,
      required this.text,
      required this.sizeW,
      required this.sizeH});

  @override
  State<Buttons> createState() => _ButtonsState();
}

class _ButtonsState extends State<Buttons> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.sizeW,
      height: widget.sizeH,
      child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => _loginScreen(),
          child: Text(
            widget.text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
          color: widget.backgroundColor,
          textColor: widget.textColor,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(22.0))),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas definir el método a llamar en tu widget, sería un `VoidCallback`, algo así :

```
class Buttons extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color textColor;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final String text;
  final double sizeW;
  final double sizeH;
  // puedes usar cualquier nombre, yo solo puse `onPressed`.
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  const Buttons(
      {super.key,
      required this.textColor,
      required this.backgroundColor,
      required this.text,
      required this.sizeW,
      required this.sizeH,
      required this.onPressed,
 });
```

Al momento de usar ese parámetro en tu `State`, lo harías así :

```dart
 RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => widget.onPressed(),
          // o también así: 
          // onPressed: widget.onPressed,
```

Y para usarlo desde otra clase, sería así :

```dart
Center(
child: Buttons(
    onPressed: () => _loginScreen(),
    // tus demás parámetros
    // ...
 ),
);
```

Comment: Gracias!! Me ha servido

Comment: puedes marcar la pregunta como resuelta :)

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias! Podrías ayudarme con esta -- > https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548161/como-puedo-crear-un-bot%c3%b3n-y-que-me-permita-reutilizarlo-y-as%c3%ad-navegar-en-pantal/548257?noredirect=1#comment1009201_548257